# Can an instance of the post correspondence problem have exactly one solution?

Tags: computability

Can an instance of the Post Correspondence Problem (PCP) have exactly one solution?

Answer (score 2):

Either the instance has no solutions or you can obtain infinitely many solutions by repeating the same sequence of selected pairs of words multiple times.

More precisely, using the definitions from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem), let a solution be:
$$
\alpha_{i_1} \alpha_{i_2} \dots \alpha_{i_K} = \beta{i_1} \beta{i_2} \dots \beta{i_K},
$$
then the following is also a solution:
$$
\alpha_{i_1} \alpha_{i_2} \dots \alpha_{i_K} \alpha_{i_1} \alpha_{i_2} \dots \alpha_{i_K} = \beta{i_1} \beta{i_2} \dots \beta{i_K} \beta{i_1} \beta{i_2} \dots \beta{i_K}
$$